# What is the difference between @angular/fire and firebase for an Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

What is the difference between @angular/fire and firebase for an Angular project using firebase? They are both NPM packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `firebase` npm module packages the Firebase SDKs for use in any client-side JavaScript application. So the SDKs in there are not specific to Angular, or any other framework.

The `@angular/fire` npm module wraps the standard SDK, and provides dedicated bindings to Angular primitives. So it contains observables, it knows of zones, and more stuff you'd expect to make it easier to use in your Angular apps.

So when you use the `@angular/fire` you are *also* implicitly using the regular `firebase` SDKs, you just *also* get higher level primitives that make it easier to integrate into Angular.